# почему возвращает код а не значение

Tags: angularjs, firebase

почему возвращает код а не значение

```
$scope.profileThenEdit = {
    userEdit: function () {
        ref.child('users').child(ref.getAuth().uid).child('mailregister').once("value", function (snapshot) {
            return snapshot.child("edit").val()
        });
    }
 };
 $scope.$watch('profileThenEdit.userEdit', function (dataLoaded) {
    console.log(dataLoaded);
    //if (dataLoaded) {
    //    $location.path('profile');
    //} else {
    //    $location.path('editprofile');
    //}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что отслеживается значение свойства *profileThenEdit.userEdit* - это свойство **функция**

Таким образов в лог выводится сама функция, а не результат ее вызова.

Ну и стоит обратить внимание на то, что данная функция **ничего не возвращает**

Comment: что нужно сделать чтобы изменить это ?

Comment: @DavidKern, все зависит от того, что в итоге надо получить, как минимум нужно отслеживать не функцию. Скорее всего тут вообще не нужно использование _$watch_, но для полного ответа, нужно, как я уже писал в комментарии к предыдущему удаленному вопросу, добавить [mcve], потому что сейчас неизвестно что вообще используется и что должно получиться в итоге

Comment: при регистрации я посылаю значение 0  , в firebase потом когда я захожу на сайт я хочу получить этo значение . и в if спросить если 0 то переходит на страницу edit если 1 то на profile но сам if вызывается быстрее чем я получаю данные

Comment: @DavidKern, поэтому я и хочу **[mcve]**, по описанию абсолютно непонятно что есть сейчас, какие дополнительные библиотеки используются и т.д.

Comment: @DavidKern, я уже несколько раз дал ссылку на справку где описано, что такое [mcve], стоит прочитать об этом и все-таки добавить его

Comment: так я тут все ипревол  angular & firebase послать весь контроллер ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43636/discussion-between-grundy-and-david-kern).